# Mockito bug when testing Optional.map()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, optional-chaining

Here is my implementation:

```
List<Calendar> fetch(String input) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(input)
            .map(client::getCalendars)
            .orElse(repository.fetch());
}
```

And the test:

```
@Test
void fetchGetsDataFromHolidayClient() {
    //Given
    String input = "search by post code or city";
    List<Calendar> expected = singletonList(mock(Calendar.class));
    doReturn(expected).when(client).getCalendars(input);
    // When
    List<Calendar> actual = service.fetch(input);
    // Then
    verify(client).getCalendars(input);
    verify(repository, never()).fetch();
    assertThat(expected).isEqualTo(actual);
}
```

Test failed the result below:

Never wanted here:
-> at ServiceTest.fetchGetsDataFromHolidayClient(ServiceTest.java:57)
But invoked here:
-> at Service.fetch(Service.java:39)

**Calendar is my POJO**, It isn't java.util.Calendar!
I used Oracle JK 8, Junit5.
Is this a bug of mockito?

Comment: For starters, there's no point in mocking values like `Calendar`; just use a real one. Furthermore, you don't seem to be testing `fetch` but rather `fetch2`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, firstly thanks for your comment. Calendar is my Object, It doesn't come from the java.util. Then, fetch 2 is my typo mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug but rather the `orElse` is evaluated when the optional has a non null value.

You need `orElseGet`. So, repository call will be made only when needed. -

```
List<Calendar> fetch(String input) {
return Optional.ofNullable(input)
        .map(client::getCalendars)
        .orElseGet(() -> repository.fetch());
}
```